# How to delete the original image after resizing it

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I have images upload script, there when we upload an image or images then the function resize it and
    make two images from the original image, one is 205 * 256 and the other is 800 * 500. The image 
    resize is working properly but the problem is that when i upload and resize the image then the
    original image also moved to the directory...i want that only the resized images be in my 
    directory....now the question is that how can i remove the original image from the directory...i
    don't want the original image in the directory..mean the original image not move to   directory..Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
if($_POST['btnSubmit'])
{
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);$i++)
{
if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i] !=""))
{
$images = $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($images);
if($width>600 && $height>480)
{
$new_images = "Thumbnails_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i],"$output_dir".$_FILES["fileUpload"]   ["name"][$i]);
$res = resize(800,500,$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i],$_FILES["fileUpload"]["type"][$i]); 
$width=205;
$height=256;
$size=GetimageSize($res);
$images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($res);
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($images_fin,"$output_dir".$new_images);
ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
echo "Resize Successful.<br>";
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("datbase");
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO gallery ";
$strSQL .="(id,filename,Thumbnails) VALUES ('','".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i]."','".$new_images."')";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);


}
else
{
//upload the image with out changing
}

?>



//This is the resize function
<?php
$output_dir = "MyResize/";
function resize($width, $height,$image,$type){
global $output_dir;
$relPath = $output_dir.$image;
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($relPath);
/* calculate new image size with ratio */
$ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
$h = ceil($height / $ratio);
$x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
$w = ceil($width / $ratio);
/* new file name */
$thumb = $output_dir.$width.'x'.$height.'_'.$image;
//echo $thumb; exit;
/* read binary data from image file */
$imgString = file_get_contents($relPath);
//echo $imgString ; exit;
/* create image from string */
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
//echo $image; exit;
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
0, 0,
$x, 0,
$width, $height,
$w, $h);
/* Save image */
switch ($type) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    {
        //echo $tmp; exit;
        imagejpeg($tmp,$thumb,100);
        break;

    }
    case 'image/jpg':
    {
        imagejpeg($tmp,$thumb,100);
        break;

    }
    case 'image/png':
    {
        imagepng($tmp, $thumb, 0);
        break;
    }
    case 'image/gif':
    {
        imagegif($tmp, $thumb);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
return $thumb;
/* cleanup memory */
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($tmp);
}
?>
```

Comment: `unlink($originalImagePath);`

Comment: Removed the cakephp flag as this is cleary not even remotely cakephp related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to delete image, use [unlink('Path to the file')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Similar to the Unix C unlink() function. A E_WARNING level error will be generated on failure

Comment: i put the unlink($output_dir) after resize function call but its not working

Comment: $output_dir should contain path till image name, e.g path/to/test.jpg

Comment: @AbdulMuheet What a wholesome desi way to say "thank you"!  :D

Answer (score 2):

first crop the image and store that image and then use unlink to delete the orignal image

```
    unlink('Orignal image path');
```

unlink will delete the orignal image from folder